# Why Spring Security .antMatchers is not found?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, deprecated

I need a SecurityConfig file to verify roles without "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" who is deprecated.

Here is my pom.xml dependencies for spring security :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And here is my SecurityConfig.java class :

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic();


        return http.build();

    }

}
```

For the context, I watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4X4SJv2RrU&t=522s).

I run mvn clean, validate and try to clear IntelliJ cache with File -> Invalidate Cache, but with no success. Problem persist "Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'" on antMatchers methods.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security 5.8, the `antMatchers`, `mvcMatchers`, and `regexMatchers` methods were deprecated in favor of new `requestMatchers` method. Above deprecated methods were removed in Spring Security 6.0

Check the [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think `antMatchers` is deprecated and removed from latest Spring Security. You may use `requestMatchers` instead of `antMatchers`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic();
        
        return http.build();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#use-new-requestmatchers), from *Spring Security 5.8* the `.antMatchers()` method as been *deprecated*. And from *Spring Security 6* they have been *removed*. Spring has provided this new method `.requestMatchers()`

So, your **SecurityConfig.java** should looks something like this:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
            .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2022/12/01/spring-security-6/) you can find what's new in Spring Security 6. Hope it helps.